# Kivy's ScreenManager: switch_to does not seem to work as specified in the docs

Tags: kivy

According to the docs, the previous screen should be removed from the children:

> switch_to(screen, **options)¶
>
> Add a new screen to the ScreenManager and switch to it.
>   **The previous screen will be removed from the children.**
>   options are the transition options that will be changed before the animation happens.

see: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to

However, when using switch_to the previous screen does not seem to be removed.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen(name='menu'))
print sm.screen_names
sm.switch_to(Screen(name='settings'))
print sm.screen_names
```

Result:

```
['menu']

['menu', 'settings']
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug?

Edit: I expected that the 'menu' screen should be removed after switching to the 'settings' screen. But it is still there. What does the statement **The previous screen will be removed from the children.** actually mean?

Comment: provide a [mcve] :)

Comment: There might be a slight delay between a call to `switch_to()` and the removal of the previous `Screen`. Try executing the `print sm.screen_names` using `Clock.schedule_once()` (or something to give the removal some time to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The removal of the old screen is triggered by the completion of the `SlideTransition` that occurs by default when  a `Screen` is switched to. Since your screens have nothing in them, no transition is performed, and the removal never gets triggered. Also, since the removal is triggered by an event, it does not happen immediately. Here is an example that displays the expected behavior:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

def do_print(*args):
    print 'After some delay: ' + str(sm.screen_names)

sm = ScreenManager()

class SwitchToApp(App):
    def build(self):
        scr1 = Screen(name='menu')
        scr1.add_widget(Label(text='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(scr1)
        print sm.screen_names
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_switch_to, 1)
        return sm

    def do_switch_to(self, *args):
        scr2 = Screen(name='settings')
        scr2.add_widget(Label(text='settings'))
        sm.switch_to(scr2)
        print 'immediately after switch_to: ' + str(sm.screen_names)
        Clock.schedule_once(do_print, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchToApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked and I understand the explanation. Could I also use the on_leave event for scr1 or may this result in a race condition? "on_leave" is fired when the screen is removed, i.e the leaving animation is finished. But maybe "switch_to" removes the screen before the the screen can fire the event!?

Comment: @Tachezi, You can still use the `on_leave` event.